# how to set accuracy of android proximity alert

Tags: android, proximity

I want to know the accuracy for the every fired proximity alert. Is there any way to get that information? can I use locationManager.getLastKnownLocation()? Is there any way to tell the system not to fire alerts if the accuracy is bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know the accuracy for the every fired proximity alert. Is there any way to get that information?

Every update called on your `LocationListener` is passed a `Location` object for the new event.  This object has methods like `getAccuracy()` that you can use to obtain that information.

> Is there any way to tell the system not to fire alerts if the accuracy is bad?

`LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`, only allows you to control the frequency of updates based on time between or distance between each update.  It does not allow you to control getting updates from the manager based on accuracy; you will need to use the information from the update to decide whether or not to keep each report.

Comment: Thaks for your fast answer. I know the method getAccuracy() works fine when using requestLocationUpdates(). But the proximity Alerts for android doesn't require requestLocationUpdates().Are you sure getAccuracy works for proximity alerts too?

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question.  Since the location data is not passed along with the proximity alert Intent, you are correct that using getLastKnownLocation() is the best opportunity you have to evaluate the accuracy of where the device thinks it currently is.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if getLastKnownLocation() gives me the actual location that android proximity uses. I really want to know it. For my application I am using getLastKnownLocation() in order to determine the accuracy for the coordinate that proximity service uses (using location.getAccuracy) and it seems to work. If somebody can answer my question, be welcome. Thanks for your answer Devunwired.